# testing an asynchronous web service using JMeter

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous, soap, jmeter

I'd like to use JMeter to test an asynchronous web service. Namely, JMeter is used to send Soap requests to a webservice (invoking some WSDL defined routines) and the webservice will queue these operations for later execution. It will respond with a notification for each operation that is executed.

I would like to be able to track the latency between request and response for each request sent.

Since the request and response happen asynchronously, I would need a way of mapping each request that I send to the response which may come back later.

Can someone point me to the simplest way of doing this in JMeter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way I see is to setup a thread simulating each user.

After sending the request, the thread polls for the response, which is the way a browser would work.

Obviously, this cannot be done when the time between request and response is long, and/or volumes become very large. In this case, you probably would need to log each event and to calculate time duration offline.